# Как считать данные из адресной строки браузера на с#?

Tags: c#, .net, pcap

Всем привет. 
Стоит задача получить название вводимого адреса сайта в адресную строку браузера.
Реализовать это хочу на языке с#. Полазив в интернете нарыл информацию о том что это можно делать с помощью специальных библиотек WinPcap (версия для windows). 
Но не знаю верно ли это, и можно ли вообще перехватывать пакеты со своего же ПК, и не знаю как это делать. Прошу помогите советом.

Comment: Перехватывать можно всё, один из ярких примеров Fiddler он проксирует все запросы, а вот на сколько это этично решает каждый сам для себя. К примеру я был бы против программы которая рылась бы в моей адресной строке .(где вы такие берётесь ?)

Comment: Я же не буду ни где фиксировать эти данные, они мне нужны для других целей. Всё вполне этично. A Fiddler это прокси, а мне нужно что то типа библиотеки, для моего проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри Titanium webproxy, он как раз может перехватить абсолютно все исходящие с машины запросы. Можно взять нужную часть, добавить фильтр по процессам и все ок.

Comment: Вы про этот Titanium? https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy Если да, то помогите пожалуйста разобраться что к чему, я совсем запутался. Тут и классы есть с кодом и Nuget его можно скачать. И как быть?

Comment: да, с чем возникла проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не пойму код. Я собственно скачал с github, а  как запустить не знаю. Не получается собственно. Пожалуйста помогите. Я создал новый консольный проект. Установил через nuget Titanium.Web.Proxy и добавил с этого форума [http://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=26:43127] код программы

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, какую часть взять и какие фильтры добавить. Или хотя бы дайте подсказку. Плииииз